# How to do leave one out cross validation with tensor-flow (Keras)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, cross-validation

I have 20 subjects and I want to use the leave one out cross-validation when I train the model that has implemented with Tensorflow. I follow some instructions and finally here is my pseudo code:

```
for train_index, test_index in loo.split(data):
print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
train_X=np.concatenate(np.array([data[ii][0] for ii in train_index]))
train_y=np.concatenate(np.array([data[ii][1] for ii in train_index]))

test_X=np.concatenate(np.array([data[ii][0] for ii in test_index]))
test_y=np.concatenate(np.array([data[ii][1] for ii in test_index]))


train_X,train_y = shuffle(train_X, train_y)
test_X,test_y = shuffle(test_X, test_y)



#Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

#keras.initializers.RandomNormal(mean=0.0, stddev=0.05, seed=None)

#Train the model
model.fit(train_X, train_y, batch_size=16, epochs=30,validation_split=.10)#,callbacks=[])

#test accuracy
test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_X,test_y)
print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)
```

but the results after the first subject are like this:

```
Epoch 30/30
3590/3590 [==============================] - 4s 1ms/sample - loss: 0.5976 - 
**acc: 0.8872** - val_loss: 1.3873 - val_acc: 0.6591


255/255 [==============================] - 0s 774us/sample - loss: 1.8592 - 
acc: 0.4471

Test accuracy: 0.44705883
```

second iteration (Subject):

```
TRAIN: [ 0  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17] TEST: [1]

Train on 3582 samples, validate on 398 samples
Epoch 1/30
3582/3582 [==============================] - 5s 1ms/sample - loss: 0.7252 - 
**acc: 0.8238** - val_loss: 1.0627 - val_acc: 0.6859
```

It sounds that the model uses previous weights! If we look at the first accuracy of the second iteration, it starts from acc: 0.8238!

Is my implementation correct? or I need more steps to initial weight for each subject?

Answer (score 0):

The 0.8238 is the training data acc, not on your test data. Your fit() method also has a validation split for the training data.

The model works fine from what I see. Your implementation is correct.

Comment: Not sure!
For each subject, the training should be independent of others, but it's not!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the line below before compile inside your for loop:

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```

This will delete all of the graph and session information stored by Tensorflow including your graph weights. You can check the source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.14/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L217-L242) and an explanation of what it does [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/clear_session)